# How to set Stack Series false for particular series of Data in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, charts, jqplot

I am using the jqPlot chart in one of my project.

I am creating the chart same as like below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8QiA.jpg

The charts are working fine, but the line chart values should not get stack. But, in my code, the line series values also getting stacked.

For Example: Over all Stacked bar chart value is 10, the line chart value is 50. But, In my scenario the line chart value is plotting at the position 60 instead of 50.

My Code is below.

```
plot = $.jqplot(chartId, [d1, d2, d3], {
        seriesColors: ["#d82b25", "#707b7f", "#083a6d"],
        title: titles,
        stackSeries: true,
        animate: true,
        animateReplot: true,
        cursor: {
            style: 'pointer',
            show: true,
            zoom: false,
            looseZoom: false,
            showTooltip: false
        },
        series:[
            {
                pointLabels: {
                    show: false
                },
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                showHighlight: true,
                yaxis: 'yaxis',
                rendererOptions: {
                    animation: {
                        speed: 2500
                    },
                    barWidth: 12,
                    barPadding: 20,
                    barMargin: 0,
                    highlightMouseOver: false
                }
            },
            {
                pointLabels: {
                    show: false
                },
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                showHighlight: true,
                yaxis: 'yaxis',
                rendererOptions: {
                    animation: {
                        speed: 2500
                    },
                    barWidth: 12,
                    barPadding: 20,
                    barMargin: 20,
                    highlightMouseOver: false
                }
            },
            {
                yaxis: 'y2axis',
                rendererOptions: {
                    animation: {
                        speed: 2000
                    }
                },
                markerOptions: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            show: true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                numberRows: 2
            },
            location: 's',
            placement: 'outside',
            labels: types,
            yoffset: 52
        },
        axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            labelOptions: {
                fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                fontSize: '10pt'
            },
            tickOptions: {
                fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                fontSize: '10pt'
            },
            pad: 0
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks,
                drawMajorGridlines: false,
                tickOptions:{
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, 
                    angle:-90
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                showGridline: false,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: "%.1f"
                },
                rendererOptions: {
                    forceTickAt0: true
                },
                label:'Volume($ Billions)',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            },
            y2axis: {
                showGridline: false,
                tickOptions: {
                    show: true,
                    formatString: "%.1f"
                },
                rendererOptions: {
                    alignTicks: true,
                    forceTickAt0: true
                },
                label:'US($ Millions)',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            }
        },
        grid:{
            background: '#ffffff',
            borderColor: '#333333',
            borderWidth: 1.0,
            gridLineColor: '#575757'
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true, 
            showLabel: true, 
            tooltipAxes: 'y',
            sizeAdjust: 7.5,
            tooltipLocation : 'ne'
        }
    });
```

Please kindly some one help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you please provide some sample data for your code or if u can prepare a jsfiddle for your code that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If to look at the source code of the jqPlot framework and search for `stackSeries` line, you can find that it is used so:

```
if (this.stackSeries && !series.disableStack)
```

And according to the [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.disableStack) the `disableStack` property is what you need.

> true to not stack this series with other series in the plot.  To render properly, non-stacked series must come after any stacked series in the plot’s data series array.

Your line non-stacked series is placed after the bar stacked series, so this parameter will work properly. Use it so:

```
series:[
    { //...
    },
    { // ...
    },
    {
        disableStack: true,
        yaxis: 'y2axis',
        rendererOptions: {
            animation: {
                speed: 2000
            }
        },
        markerOptions: {
            show: false
        }
    }
]
```