# How to disable Stacking on an individual series using Primefaces jQplot implementation

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jqplot

I am using Primefaces 6 for my companys charting needs, which relies on jQplot.
For a project, I am trying to overlay a line chart on a stacked bar chart with negative values,  to obtain something like this:

[image: Account Retention Visualisation]

The problem is that when I try to add a `linechartseries` to the same model as the two `barchartseries` , the linechart becomes a part of the stack when setting `setStacked(true);` on the model, because Primefaces seems to not allow individual disabling of stacking on series, only per model. So I end up with this when rendering the chart with

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{backingBean.cartesianChartModel}"/>
```

[image: Line Chart as part of the Stack]

After some investigation I have notoced that jQplot is capable of disabling Stacking on individual series by passing `disableStack : true` in the JS options, so the question is if it's posssible to override this in some way on the rendered page,either via PF or via some JS hack? I feel that using the extender only apples to the entire model?

Related issues: [Disable individual stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946952/how-to-set-stack-series-false-for-particular-series-of-data-in-jqplot)

Comment: _" I feel that using the extender only apples to the entire model?"_ Try... look at examples... Don't draw conclusions upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pouring through the documentation I found a solution to the problem, if not the question:

It seems that Primefaces allows for individual series to be excempt from the stack in the series creation in this version, by passing

```
LineChartSeries.setDisableStack(true);
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it may be possible.  I used the extender functionality for some jqPlot hacks in the past.

In my case, for example, I had a Donut Chart defined with an extender function as follows:

```
    private void createDonutModel() {
       donutModel = new DonutChartModel();
       donutModel.setLegendPosition("s");
       donutModel.setLegendPlacement(LegendPlacement.OUTSIDE);
       donutModel.setSliceMargin(4);
       donutModel.setDataFormat("value");
       donutModel.setShadow(false);
       donutModel.setExtender("donutExtender");
       donutModel.setSeriesColors("B81C40, FFA600, 79B54A");
    }
```

The corresponding javascript was doing some changes to the jqPlot:

```
/**
 * Customized jqPlot JQuery layout of the Donut Chart for Status Dashboard.
 */
function donutExtender() {
   this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
      // make this a donut chart.
      renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions:{          
          thickness: 26,
          ringMargin: 0,
          fill: true,
          padding: 0,
        sliceMargin: 4,
        // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
        startAngle: -90,
        showDataLabels: false,
        // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
        // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead, or 'percent'
        dataLabels: 'value',
            shadow: false
      }
   }                

   this.cfg.gridPadding = { 
        top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0                
   }

   this.cfg.legend = {
        show: false
   }

   this.cfg.grid = { drawBorder: false,
        shadow: false,        
        background: "transparent"
   };
}
```

So you may try something like this in your case ?
Leave the extension configuration of your series empty, except for the one you are interested in...

```
function chartExtender() {
   this.cfg.series = [
   { //...
   },
   { // ...
   },
   {
      disableStack: true          
   }
   ]
}
```

Worth having a shot ...